# Saving multiple checkboxes to Django ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have this form field:

```
class NewVenueForm(forms.Form):    
      features = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), queryset=hmod.Feature.objects.all(), required=False)
```

And this model:

```
class Feature(models.Model):
    '''A feature that a listing has'''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And this HTML:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <div {% if form.title.errors %}class="field_error"{% endif %}>
             Venue Title
             {{ form.title }}
             {{ form.title.errors }}
        </div>
        Features
         <br/>
         {% for key, value in form.features.field.choices %}
             <input type="checkbox" id="{{value}}" value="{{key}}" name="feature">
                 <label for="{{value}}">
                     {{ value }}
                 </label>
         {% endfor %} 

         <input type="submit" value="Save">
      </div>
</form>
```

The checkboxes look like they are working, but I'm having trouble saving multiple selections to the features Django form field.

My views.py looks like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NewVenueForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid(): 
         print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
         print(form.cleaned_data['features'])
```

I've experimented with actually saving the values to the model, but realized that I'm not even getting past this point . . . printing out the form.cleaned_data returns an empty list: []!!

Any ideas? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You didn't call `form.is_valid()` before trying to get `form.cleaned_data`, right?

Comment: Ah. Yes, I did. Just forgot to paste that code in the question :) Thanks @ShangWang

Comment: Just to make sure, is form populated w/ data by calling `form = FeaturesForm(request.POST)` before this? Since the solitary field in your form is not required, it would still be valid if no data passed to it.

Comment: Does the view work if you use `{{ form.feature }}` instead of rendering the field manually? What does your form look like?

Comment: Please show `NewVenueForm` and the contents of the entire `<form>` tag from the template.

Comment: Yes, I did have that and also forgot to add it to the post! Sorry, I thought I had included all the relevant pieces :) Thanks @IanPrice

Comment: @Alasdair I added some extra information about the form :) And it appears to work ok when I use {{  form.features }} but I want to render the field manually because of some CSS I'm using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is a simple typo. You have `name="feature"`, which doesn't match the field name `features`. It should be:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{value}}" value="{{key}}" name="features">
```

As an aside, I would avoid using `id={{ value }}`. If you let Django render the field for you with `{{ form.features }}`, then the input ids will be `id_features_0`, `id_features_1` and so on. It would be better to use something like `id="id_feature_{{ key }}` - keys for a model multiple choice field should be unique, but the values might not be. If you change this, you'll need to update `<label for="{{value}}">` to match.

Comment: Bro you kidding me?!? I can't believe it. Thank you so much - that was it! Sometimes it just takes another pair of eyes. I really appreciate it - thank you thank you! And yes I'll take your advice on the id's. Smart.